# Are exceptional divisors always projectivations of normal bundles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

[My question is based on  an answer on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/164144/129751)

I quote the sections relevant to my question:

> Let $ Y \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} $ be a smooth variety, and let $ \epsilon: X = \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}\mathbb{P}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n} $ be the blowup of $ \mathbb{P}^{n} $ along $ Y. $ Let $ \widetilde{H} $ be the pullback of the hyperplane section $ H $ of $ \mathbb{P}^{n}, $ and $ E $ be the exceptional divisor.
>
> Recall that $ E = \mathbb{P}(N_{Y/\mathbb{P}^{n}}). $

**Question:** I would appreciate a bit of background as to why $ E = \mathbb{P}(N_{Y/\mathbb{P}^{n}}). $

Comment: How much do you know about blowing up? For instance, what is your definition?

Comment: @KReiser I'm not entirely sure that this is the proper definition, but: Let $ \overline{X} \subset \mathbb{P}^{n} $ is projective with homogeneous coordinate ring $ S(\overline{X}), $ and let  $ Y $ be a subvariety. Let $ F_{1},\dots,F_{r} $ be generators(of equal degree) of a homogeneous ideal $ I \subset S(\overline{X}). $ Define $ \varphi: \overline{X} \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{r-1}, x \mapsto [F_{1}(x):\dots:F_{r}(x)]. $ Then $ \operatorname{Bl}_{I}\overline{X} = \Gamma_{\varphi} \subset \overline{X} \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}. $

Comment: @KReiser $ \operatorname{Bl}_{\overline{Y}}\overline{X} = \operatorname{Bl}_{\mathbb{I}(\overline{Y})}\overline{X}, $ and $ \operatorname{Bl}_{Y}X = \operatorname{Bl}_{\overline{Y}}\overline{X} \cap (X \times \mathbb{P}^{n-1}). $

Answer (score 2):

Here is a picture without any real math. Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ be a smooth curve, e.g. the twisted cubic curve. (Top half of the picture). Then $Bl_C(\mathbb{P}^3)$ looks like $\mathbb{P}^3$ with $C$ replaced by a curving tube $E$. (Bottom half of the picture).

At each point $c \in C$, there is now, instead, a little $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is really the projectivized normal vectors to $c$. I have drawn one such fiber $F$ in green.

To see how this plays out, suppose $C'$ is another smooth curve intersecting $C$ transversely at $c$. Then in the blowup, the strict transform of $C'$, call it $\tilde{C'}$, intersects $E$ at the point $(c, \langle v\rangle ) \in F$ where $\langle v\rangle$ is the tangent direction corresponding to the tangent line of $C'$.

(Note: since $F$ is a $\mathbb{P}^1$, I have cheated and drawn the picture so it looks like there are two points of intersection. But there's just one.) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDZyw.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this picture. I see how the exceptional divisors can arise from projectivized normal vectors at a point. Is $ v $ exactly the tangent vector at the point where $ C' $ meets $ E? $

Comment: Yes, that's right. Actually, now that you mention it, since it is the projectivized tangent vector, the right terminology would be the "tangent direction" of $C'$. I'll edit the post.

Comment: My bad, I meant the tangent vector where $ \overline{C'} $ meets $ E. $ The way I see it, that's a vector perpendicular to the vector represented by the red arrow on the bottom half of the picture. Or am I suddenly confusing things? I'm suddenly not seeing how the point $ (c,\langle v \rangle) \in F $ arises if $ v $ is the tangent vector of $ C' $ at $ c. $

Comment: By definition, the normal space to $C$ at $c$ is the quotient $T_c\mathbb{P}^3 / T_c C$. This is two-dimensional, so its projectivization is $\mathbb{P}^1$. We can't really talk about perpendicularity, but in the $\mathbb{P}^3$ picture, the tangent vector along $C'$ at $c$ gives a nonzero element of this quotient since $C$ and $C'$ aren't aligned at $c$ (and so $T_c C'$ descends to a line in this quotient, i.e. a point on the $\mathbb{P}^1$). This corresponds to the location of $\tilde{C'} \cap E$.